# Storing complex string in REdis

Tags: json, redis

we're trying to use Redis (HMSET) to store basically a CLOB pulled from Oracle, which is really just a long JSON string.    We are trying it like this:

```
HMSET 279479 article_id 279479
HMSET 279479 old_article_id 385650
HMSET 279479 json_content {"section_1":{"section_publish":true,"section_body":"<p style=\"text-align: justify;\">NextEra Energy..........."section_28":{"section_publish":true,"section_body":""},"section_29":{"section_publish":true,"section_body":""}}
```

The first 2 items are stored just fine, but the 3rd item, json_content, appears as 'nil'.   Is there something about the string, or escaping certain characters, or the like that we need to do?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I usually wrap JSON in single quotes. Should solve your particular problem handily as well.

Comment: And if the data itself has single ticks?   Won't that confuse things?

Comment: You can escape with \